# Any way to configure source code in a namespaced scratch org to have a package version number?

Tags: managed-package, salesforcedx, scratch-org, package-dependency

We have some **dependent** managed packages. In our build, in scratch orgs, we install a first managed package that a second managed package depends on but instead of installing the second managed package we can push that package's source code in and run the tests. All good.

I now need to reverse this to do some governor limit debugging. That is, I want to have the **source code of the first managed package in the scratch org and install the second managed package that depends on the first**. But I get this error:

> Package "First Package Name", Version 12.1 or later must be installed first.

So while the code pushed into the scratch org has a namespace defined, it does not have a package version number. Or perhaps it is not considered to be present at all as far as dependent package installation is concerned. I had a look around the `project-scratch-def.json` and `sfdx-project.json` documentation in case there is a way to set a version number for this purpose; there is a `versionNumber` property in the latter but no joy with that so far e.g. VSCode says "Property versionNumber is not allowed".

It looks like this arrangement is not supported to me. Is it?

Comment: Installing both packages unmanaged wouldn't meet your needs, I take it?

Comment: @DavidReed Perhaps as a fallback though there may be component name collisions with the namespaces dropped.

Comment: Looks like I misread the question... No, you can't do what you're trying to do, AFAIK, because you need to have the managed package already uploaded in an org before you can install its dependencies. I'd reach out to the DX team for confirmation, but I'm pretty sure you can't do what you're trying to do.

Comment: @sfdcfox Thanks yeah it seems unlikely that it is supported given the historic nature of the current packaging mechanism.

Comment: Outside chance it could work if you create a 2GMP with the same namespace as the base package and install it, provided the second package doesn't have any explicit references to the first package's namespace. (Disclaimer: I don't know the underlying semantics of the dependency resolution - i.e., whether it really checks NS + version or the 04t IDs).

Comment: Hi @KeithC, I think you are out of luck, versionNumber seems to be just the placeholder for 2GP when you upload the package (don't seem to be used while creating scratch orgs).